# Как в коде образуется запись using system.data.sqlclient

Tags: c#, sql-server

Я создал простое приложение на C# (Visual studio 2015). Создал БД и создал таблицу в этой БД. Организовал, чтобы данные в таблице отображались в приложении.

Хотел добавить в приложение возможность редактирования записи БД. Там, как мне кажется, нужно в программе добавить `using system.data.sqlclient`. Как это сделать?

Comment: `using system.data.sqlclient` - это просто стока в коде. Если она вам нужна - откройте cs-файл в текстовом редакторе и напечатайте ее :)

Answer (score 1):

На форма нажимаете `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`0`. Открывается исходный код для вашей формы. В самом верху, где есть уже другие `uses ...` вписываете нужную строку.